# Multi dropdown submenu not showing correctly

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have working on multilevel drop down menu.It looks like drop down menu inside a drop down menu.when I click the inside drop down menu it doesn't show right side,it opens below the menu.I want to show the inside drop down menu as right side like a stair case.How to solve this issue?

My code here

```
<li class="dropdown">
   <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">E-magazine
      <b class="caret"></b>
   </a>
   <ul class="dropdown-menu">
       <li class="dropdown-submenu">
         <li><a href="../Home/Emag">Valarum Vinnarasu</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">The Throne</a></li>
       </li>
   </ul>
</li>
<li><a href="../Home/childrenhome">Children Home</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
```

Comment: post a working demo with all the actual code.

Answer (score 0):

You have tag mistakes in your code maybe its help. Show your css, to see how you realize dropdown

```
<ul>
  <li class="dropdown"><a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">E-magazine<b class="caret"></b></a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
      <li class="dropdown-submenu">
        <ul>
          <li><a href="../Home/Emag">Valarum Vinnarasu</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">The Throne</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a href="../Home/childrenhome">Children Home</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use JavaScript to do that.

Example of JavaScript code:

```js
function showNested(caller) {
    var elem = caller;
    var child = $(":first-child", elem);
    if (child.is(":visible"))
       child.hide();
    else
       child.show();
}
```

and HTML:

```
<ul>
   <li>List item one</li>
   <li><a href="#" id="elemId1" onclick="showNested(this);">List item two with subitems:
      <ul id="innerList" style="display: none">
         <li>Subitem 1</li>
         <li>Subitem 2</li>
      </ul>
   </a></li>
   <li>Final list item</li>
</ul>
```

How it works:
It react onclick event. When you click element the showNested function run and pass caller as argument. it find first child element of caller (inner list) and display it. When you click it again it hide it. You can use that function for few nested list.
You can use onmouseover event.